# Kafka Streams: action on n-th event

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I'm trying to find the best way how to perform an action on *n*-th event in Kafka Streams.

My case: I have an input stream with some *Events*. I have to filter them by *eventType == login* and on each *n*-th login (let's say, fifth) for the same *accountId* send this *Event* to the output stream.

After some investigation and different tries, I have the version of the code below (I'm using Kotlin).

```
data class Event(
    val payload: Any = {},
    val accountId: String,
    val eventType: String = ""
)
```

```
// intermediate class to keep the key and value of the original event
data class LoginEvent(
    val eventKey: String,
    val eventValue: Event
)
```

```
fun process() {
        val userLoginsStoreBuilder = Stores.keyValueStoreBuilder(
            Stores.persistentKeyValueStore("logins"),
            Serdes.String(),
            Serdes.Integer()
        )
        val streamsBuilder = StreamsBuilder().addStateStore(userCheckInsStoreBuilder)
        val inputStream = streamsBuilder.stream<String, String>(inputTopic)

        inputStream.map { key, event ->
            KeyValue(key, json.readValue<Event>(event))
        }.filter { _, event -> event.eventType == "login" }
             .map { key, event -> KeyValue(event.accountId, LoginEvent(key, event)) }
             .transform(
                    UserLoginsTransformer("logins", 5),
                    "logins"
                )
             .filter { _, value -> value }
             .map { key, _ -> KeyValue(key.eventKey, json.writeValueAsString(key.eventValue)) }
             .to("fifth_login", Produced.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()))

        ...
    }
```

```
class UserLoginsTransformer(private val storeName: String, private val loginsThreshold: Int = 5) :
    TransformerSupplier<String, CheckInEvent, KeyValue< LoginEvent, Boolean>> {

    override fun get(): Transformer<String, LoginEvent, KeyValue< LoginEvent, Boolean>> {
        return object : Transformer<String, LoginEvent, KeyValue< LoginEvent, Boolean>> {
            private lateinit var store: KeyValueStore<String, Int>

            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            override fun init(context: ProcessorContext) {
                store = context.getStateStore(storeName) as KeyValueStore<String, Int>
            }

            override fun transform(key: String, value: LoginEvent): KeyValue< LoginEvent, Boolean> {
                val counter = (store.get(key) ?: 0) + 1
                return if (counter == loginsThreshold) {
                    store.delete(key)
                    KeyValue(value, true)
                } else {
                    store.put(key, counter)
                    KeyValue(value, false)
                }
            }

            override fun close() {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My biggest concern is that `transform` function is not thread-safe in my case. I've checked the implementation of the KV-store that is used in my case and this is RocksDB store (non-transactional) so the value may be updated between reading and comparison and the wrong event will be sent to the output.

My other ideas:

1. Use materialized views as a store without a transformer but I'm stuck with implementation.
2. Create a custom persistent KV store that will use TransactionalRocksDB (not sure if it is worth).
3. Create a custom persistent KV store that will use ConcurrentHashMap inside (it may lead to the high memory consumption in case of many users that we are expecting).

One more note: I'm using Spring Cloud Stream so maybe this framework has a built-in solution for my case but I didn't find it.

I would appreciate any suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My biggest concern is that transform function is not thread-safe in my case. I've checked the implementation of the KV-store that is used in my case and this is RocksDB store (non-transactional) so the value may be updated between reading and comparison and the wrong event will be sent to the output.

There is no reason to be concerned. If you run with multiple threads, each thread will have it's own RocksDB that store one shard of the overall data (note that the overall state is sharded based in input topic partitions and a single shard is never processed by different threads). Hence, your code will work correctly. The only thing you need to ensure is, that data is partitions by `accountId`, such that login events of a single account go to the same shard.

If you input data is already partitioned by `accountId` when written into your input topic, you don't need to do anything. If not, and you can control the upstream application, it might be simplest to use a custom partitioner in the upstream's application producer to get the partitioning you need. If you can't change the upstream application, you would need to repartition the data after you have set the `accountId` as new key, ie, by doing a `through()` before you call `transform()`.

Comment: I can't control upstream, so I need repartition. One more note - we are talking not about multiple threads (JVM threads), but about multiple consumers that are reading the same topic.

Comment: Different consumers would _always_ run on different threads using Kafka Streams.